# how to upload code to github that contains a password?

Tags: github, passwords, push, repo

I want to push my code to my github repo but it contains a password for my database. Is there a way to upload the code without manually removing the password everytime?

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to upload sensitive data to github.
But you can use git `filename.config` file to store your credentials and sensitive data.
To see an example you can check [this](https://gist.github.com/pksunkara/988716)

Other workaround is to not store your password in main code, but put it in some other file and then import in your code. Single credential file is much easy to handle.

Hint: You can also encode the credentials